# How do I listen for when a user presses a certain key like enter?

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried `document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {})`, but dont know how to listen for when a user presses enter

Comment: [Keyboard event: code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

Comment: You can read this in the documentation of MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event

Comment: But have you tried putting your title in a web search engine?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
   document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.code === 'Enter') {
        alert('Enter is pressed!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property of `event` ([keyboard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)).

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log(event.key);
  }
});
```